# i'm using a mouse filter driver, how can i install it to a specific HID-compliant mouse by cmd command?

Tags: filter-driver

I used the filter driver sample from https://github.com/microsoft/windows-driver-samples/tree/main/input/moufiltr
the driver work well on the device by:

1. select Device Manager.
2. right click on the target mouse device and select update driver
3. **cause can not find filter driver .inf file by Search automatically for drivers**, select Browse my computer for driver software
4. select Let me pick from a list of available drivers on my computer
5. select Have Disk
6. paste the .inf file path here and install
   However, this driver doesn't work by sc create /sc start or just right click on .inf file and install
   Maybe i failed to set some properties in .inf file so the driver can not point to the device?

What should i do if i want to install this driver automatically or just install the driver when the device is created